# How to insert list value in dictionary for default_get method Odoo11

Tags: list, dictionary, odoo, odoo-10

I am using default_get method for one2many fields and I can see fields in the list but when I want to pass these fields in the dictionary by the super method in show blank dictionary. So, how to get this?

**My python code is here:**

```py
@api.model
def default_get(self, fields):
    print("FIELDS", fields)
    rec = super(CrmContactLine, self).default_get(fields)
    print("REC", rec)
    context = dict(self._context or {})
    partner = self.env['res.partner'].browse(context['partner_id'])
    fields['partner_m2m'] = partner.child_ids
    return rec
```

***GOT RESULT ON TERMINAL 'FIELDS' SHOW LIST VALUES BUT 'REC' DICTIONARY NULL***

FIELDS ['name', 'email', 'designation', 'linkedln_profile', 'indentifier', 'approached_status', 'approach_date', 'email_status', 'follow_up_date', 'partner_m2m']

REC {}

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If the super call to the method `default_get` return an empty dict that it's because there will be no default values defined for that model, and that's a valid result. You need to put your own values before return the result dict rec in your case, not in the fields list. This should work for you

```py
@api.model
def default_get(self, fields):
    rec = super(CrmContactLine, self).default_get(fields)
    context = dict(self._context or {})
    partner = self.env['res.partner'].browse(context['partner_id'])
    rec['partner_m2m'] = partner.child_ids
    return rec
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution to this problem.

```py
@api.model
def default_get(self, fields):
    rec = super(CrmContactLine, self).default_get(fields)
    context = dict(self._context or {})
    partner = self.env['res.partner'].browse(context['partner_id'])
    rec['partner_m2m'] = [(6, 0, partner.child_ids.ids)]  # if your field type is many2many
    return rec
```